# Can I call in iOS a method with a return type from another one of void type?

Tags: objective-c, memory, types

I wrote a method for my iOS app of type (CoreDataSubclass *) that returns a core data object with a "fetch-or-create logic". Now I'm adding another method that only creates my core data objects at the very first app run and I thought just calling the former method from within the latest. Probably I wouldn't need anymore the "create" part in the original method, but then it comes up a bit of a conceptual question, can I call a method with a return type from another one of void type? Is the memory allocated for the object just deallocated because nobody is keeping a pointer to the created object?

Thank you.

Comment: yes, you'd just create something in order to destroy it, but if it's core data it will likely also be added to the context so may get saved somewhere and actually exist...

Comment: Good point @wain. I save context at the end of my (void) method, I guess reset context would guarantee a clean context at start. Thank you.